# Finding The DSN To My Database?

Tags: sql, vba, adodb

I have an SQL database and want to connect to it using VBA in order to support some legacy functionality.  I'm using an ADODB connection and need to know what my database DSN is.  How can I find this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008, thanks! :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A DSN ([data source name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name)) is an indirect way of referring to the database. You have to create them manually (or semi-automatically using a wizard of some kind). Go to `ControlPanel->AdministrativeTools->DataSources (ODBC)` to see if one has already been defined for the database to which you want to connect.

But I think you might mean "connection string", not "DSN". There are many, many ways to tell ADODB how to find and connect to your database (`DSNs` are just one of those), but you *always* need a connection string.

I have often turned to [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to help me through the maze of similar-but-not-identical options.

Comment: +1 It would have been slightly more helpful to include what "DSN" stands for. I think it stands for "database source name," but someone correct me if that is not right (I am also new to all of this).

Comment: @Shadoninja - Edited (three years later) as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There may not *be* a DSN. DSNs are not created automatically.

---

I'm not sure you really mean DSN, as a DSN is an ODBC concept. Still, look in Administrative Tools->Data Sources (ODBC).

Comment: If there is a DSN, how can I find it?

Comment: Control Panel->Administrative Tools-> Data Sources (ODBC)